# Clearing the contents of an ajaxed form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

None of the similar questions really tackle the problem from my angle.

I have a form that register's a user. I use `.post` to handle the ajaxing. Here is the code:

```
$('#register_user_form').submit(function(){
    $.post
    (
      $(this).attr('action'),
      $(this).serialize(),
      function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $('#alert_box2').html(data);
      },
      "json"
    );
    return false;
  });
```

I know I can get by if I add `$('#input_field_id').val(' ');` before the return false. But I'd have to do this for every input field. Is there a more efficient way? Perhaps adding the same class to all fields and clearing the value of the class? I have a sense though that that would be considered "bad code".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you not just reset the form?

```
this.reset();
return false;
```

Comment: +1 If he's after a full wipe on the form, this is a better way to do it.

Comment: This is the winner of the day. `$('input').val('')` worked but it cleared the value of my submit button, thereby making it a blank button.

Comment: Note that you could always replace your input submit button with: `<button type="submit">`

Answer (score 3):

What about just:

```
$('input').val('');
```

Also, there's nothing wrong with adding a class name to each of the elements that you'd like clear.

Comment: You should use `$('#register_user_form input').val('');` in case there are more forms on the same page.

Comment: This worked but it also cleared the contents of the submit button, thus making it a blank button. `this.reset();` was more straightforward and handled it easily. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Guessing at your HTML, but you could do something like this

```
$('#register_user_form :input').each(function() {
    $(this).val('');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give a common class name for all input fields which you want to clear and do it...

```
$('classname').val('');
```

or a refresh using

```
location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It only will clear input values on the particuliar form you submit, and thus won't clear the whole document if thats an issue.

```
$('#register_user_form').submit(function(){
    var ref = $(this);
    $.post
    (
      $(this).attr('action'),
      $(this).serialize(),
      function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $('#alert_box2').html(data);
        ref.children('input').each(function(){
            $(this).val('');
        });
      },
      "json"
    );
    return false;
  });
```